# Android Application crash when adding RecyclerView Adapter to ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to create a ViewPager with the previous and next item like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W38ea.png)
and every time I set the adapter of the `ViewPager`, my application crashes.

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val list = generateDummyList(10)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val vp = binding.viewPager2
        vp.clipToPadding = false
        vp.clipChildren = false
        vp.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        vp.adapter=TransformerAdapter(list)

        val transformer: CompositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
        transformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
            val a = 1 - abs(position)
            page.scaleY = 0.85f + a * 0.15f
        }
    }

    private fun generateDummyList(size: Int): ArrayList<BigCard> {
        val list = ArrayList<BigCard>()
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val drawable = when (i % 3) {
                0 -> R.drawable.luffy
                1 -> R.drawable.luffy
                else -> R.drawable.luffy
            }
            val item = BigCard( drawable )
            list += item
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
class TransformerAdapter(private val list: List<BigCard>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TransformerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    
    class MyViewHolder(val binding: BigCardItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            BigCardItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val card = list[position]
        holder.binding.picture.setImageResource(card.picture)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size
}
```

**XML Item "big_card_item"**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advertisingText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Some Advertising Talk\nAnd Another Advertising" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertisingText"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/doctorName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Doctors Name" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/docRating"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:progressTint="@color/mid_blue"
                android:rating="4.8"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:stepSize="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/info"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:text="Check Out" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="171dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/luffy" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Data Class for Card "BigCard"**

```
data class BigCard(val picture: Int)
```

**Lines in red in logcat**

```
2021-03-06 18:18:46.503 13997-13997/com.example.testrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testrecyclerview, PID: 13997
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pages must fill the whole ViewPager2 (use match_parent)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$4.onChildViewAttachedToWindow(ViewPager2.java:270)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:754)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20846)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6266)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2910)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2425)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1521)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7437)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:965)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-03-06 18:18:46.503 13997-13997/com.example.testrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

Comment: Please provide your crash log, it will be helpful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `height:match_parent` in `RecyclerView`